# How to calculate cumulative missing values group by an ID (in python)?

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

a) given the following "id" and "freq"

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],'freq':[1,2,np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 6,7,8,9,10,np.NaN,np.NaN,13,14]})
```

df

b) how to calculate cumulative missing of "freq" group by "id"?  with a reset to zero when freq > 0

so that the result 'cum_null' should look like -
print(df(['cum_null'])
0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0

c) I've tried this.  Very close, but cannot reset to zero when freq > 0

```
df['cum_null'] = id_grp['freq'].apply(lambda x:x.isnull().astype(int).cumsum())
```

df

Comment: What is the expected output for your sample?

Comment: print(df(['cum_null'])

0 
0 
1 
2 
3 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
1 
1 
0 
0

Comment: freq always greater than 0 in your sample

Comment: 'freq" refers to number of transaction of an "id" in a given month.  so 1 mean 1 deal, 2 mean 2 deals, null mean "no" deal.

i'd like to know how the number of months w/o any transaction, i.e. count how months "freq" is null consecutively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you case you can do `groupby` with `mask`

```
df['cum_null'] = df.freq.isnull().groupby(df['id']).cumsum().where(df.freq.isnull(),0)
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     2
4     3
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    1
11    1
12    0
13    0
Name: freq, dtype: int64
```